# MySQL select with condition from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a noob question here.
I am currently developing a leads management system.
Basically I have this tables as below

[image]

What im trying to do now is when a Parent (aff_id = 740) logged-in into the system, he can see all leads created by child under him (leads from aff_id 1245, 1256 & 1301)

Below is my mySQL code. Im not that good in creating a more 'complicated' queries, but this is where i got stucked.

```
SELECT 
    leads.leads_id,
    leads.aff_id,
    leads.applied_product,
    affiliate.aff_id,
    affiliate.parent_id
FROM 
    leads, affiliate
WHERE 
    leads.aff_id = '740'
    OR
    affiliate.parent_id = '740'
```

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is parent_id_list and aid ? i cant find out any such columns from your table

Comment: Does each aff_id in the Leads table correspond to a aff_id in the Affiliate table? If so you could join the tables using the Join statement select a result that matches your criteria from the resulting table.

Comment: @AL-zami sorry about that. I copied the wrong codes. my bad. 
post edited

Comment: @Emiel yes thats what im trying to do but got stucked.
not used of using JOIN statement before

Comment: @s3polz check my answer.

Comment: @s3polz Leads.aff_id = '740' will not return anything. You should omit this from your query.It's not needed here

Comment: @AL-zami yes i just realized that removed it from my query. many thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the following query.If i understood you correctly this is something you are looking for.It will fetch all the data from leads table that's aff_id is associated with parents_id= 740 in affiliate table

```
 SELECT
    Leads.leads_id,
    Leads.applied_products,
    Leads.aff_id,
    Affiliate.parent_id
 FROM
    Leads
 INNER JOIN 
    Affiliate
 ON Leads.aff_id = Affiliate.aff_id
 WHERE Affiliate.parent_id = 740
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this query is what i need.

Comment: But what if i want to include leads made by 740 in the list as well? should i do like  `WHERE Affiliate.parent_id = 740 OR Leads.aff_id = 740` ?? is this the correct way?

Comment: you mean there could be both parent_id and aff_id 740? if that so, then yes you can use an or clause.